# TypeError: _this.props.match is undefined ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am getting TypeError at my console tab, i do not know where i am doing mistake in my source code.

 i am probably in new to reactjs. it would be great if anybody could help me out where i am doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

Repo: https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog

./src/BaseDetail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {

    state = {
        path : "",
        response : "",
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = async() => {
        const path = this.props.match.params.slug
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/${path}`);
            const JsonResponse = await response.json();
            this.setState({response:JsonResponse});
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

  render() {
    {
    const {response} = this.state;

    if (!response){
        return 'Loading...'
    }

    return (

        <div>
                <p>{response.title}</p>
                <p>{response.description}</p>

        </div>


    );
  }
}
}

export default App;
```

./src/index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>

  <Route path="/basedetail/:slug" component={BaseDetail}/>

  </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById('root')

);
```

Comment: Have you configured your Router? At what path and how is App rendered?

Comment: yes, look at my question. i have updated. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: You above code look correct. Are you sure you don't have App component rendered somewhere else too or wrapped within HOC

Comment: hey there, you can take a look at live code using remote server. which remote server are you using?

Comment: the routing of the link isn't correct in your repo - give me 15 mins to supply an answer and PR your repo

Comment: you can also post the answer here @DenisTsoi

Comment: @bounty - added PR thx

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    . Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that the props from react router wasn't being passed into `baseDetail.js`. Source: https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog/pull/5

Edit:
for the base detail component, the api endpoint is pointing to `blog_list` instead of `blog_detail` in your django `urlpatterns`
https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog/issues/6

**1. Main issue: props not being passed to child components**

The `BaseDetail.js` component wasn't passing via the constructor method, so therefore `this.props` would always return an empty object within the component.

```
class BaseDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

**2. Improvement: deep nesting of other components until it reached `BaseDetail` component.**

i.e.

```
App 
 -> BaseDetailApp 
   -> LeftAside
   -> BaseRightAside
     -> BaseDetail
```

...for React router props to be found in `BaseDetail`, you either have to pass down the props via `BaseDetailApp` and `BaseRightAside` or use something like https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router link the router and the app state.

Comment: issues did not get resolved. i am getting error, that page showing 'Loading...' instead of it taking real value.

Comment: The problem is that your implementation of fetching the detail page should be `blog_detail` not `blog_list` - i.e. a typo... - please upvote and accept the answer since this resolves the original post